# Sony HDR AS30 detect device on imac

Tags: video, mac

Does anyone know for sure if Sony HDR AS30 is only compatible with macOS 7 and up?
I know from reading docs it's only compatible for 7 and up for wifi setup but it's hard to know for desktop because there is software current for mac but no ability to input without device detection. I can see the USB connection on the mac and camera but the software is not detecting a camera.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally worked it out haha

Do not be a dummy like me and insert the memory stick upside down!

You will know when it is correctly inserted because a red light will come on indicating ready to record.